# Blender fluid simulation not working after following step by step guide

Tags: modifiers, fluid-simulation

i want to create a fluid simulation, but it didn't work as i expected. I was following this tutorial by CGCookie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B0QM4Cft5c&ab_channel=CGCookie

First, I created a liquid flow object within the domain:
[image]

Then set the domain like so:

[image]

Afterwards i ticked "mesh" and "bake all" for the domain object:

[image]

I expected the fluid simulation to play afterwards, but it seems like the domain didn't go invisible like it was supposed to and i can't see any animation.

blend file: https://we.tl/t-9CHLlLDWxU

Comment: Please provide blend file

Comment: I would change the flow from “geometry“ to “inflow.“ I have had trouble with that before.

Comment: @TheLabCat it still doesn't work. here's the blend file download: https://we.tl/t-9CHLlLDWxU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The liquid domain's voxel size is too big for your inflow object and no liquid can flow out. The voxel size is the little cube in the corner of the domain [as explained in the video](https://youtu.be/6B0QM4Cft5c?t=389).

You can either

- scale up the inflow object
- or increase the number of *Resolution Divisions* which creates smaller voxels but longer simulation baking times.

[image: screenshot]